# Creating a lift chart in R

Tags: r, graph, visualization

Suppose I have the following data frame consisting of people with some score associated with them:

```
Score | hasDefaulted
10    | 0
13    | 0
15    | 1
17    | 0
...
```

I want to make a lift chart in R by first sorting the population by score, then having % of population on the X-axis, and % of Default's on the Y-axis. I cannot find a good package that gives me the control to do this. I have explored [Package Lift](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lift/lift.pdf) as well as [Package Gains](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gains/gains.pdf) but I cannot figure out how to get enough control over them to do what I described above. For example, when I try using Package Lift, as

```
plotLift(sort(dataFrame$Score, decreasing=FALSE), dataFrame$hasDefaulted)
```

I get some strange plot:[image]

But given my desires, the plot should end up looking like a cumulative density function.

Could someone show me how to use such packages properly, or direct me to a package that does the required? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I always try to build my own code rather than trying something less flexible.

Here's how I think you can tackle the problem:

```
# Creating the data frame
df <- data.frame("Score"=runif(100,1,100),
                 "hasDefaulted"=round(runif(100,0,1),0))

# Ordering the dataset
df <- df[order(df$Score),]

# Creating the cumulative density
df$cumden <- cumsum(df$hasDefaulted)/sum(df$hasDefaulted)

# Creating the % of population
df$perpop <- (seq(nrow(df))/nrow(df))*100

# Ploting
plot(df$perpop,df$cumden,type="l",xlab="% of Population",ylab="% of Default's")
```

[image]

Is that what you want?

Comment: Yes, perfect. Thank you.

Comment: It should be `order(decreasing = TRUE)` though

Answer (score 6):

I think you are searching for a gain chart, not a lift chart. I notice there is some confusion between them. You can refer to [Lift Charts](http://www2.cs.uregina.ca/~dbd/cs831/notes/lift_chart/lift_chart.html) for more information.

```
require(ROCR)
data(ROCR.simple)
pred <- prediction(ROCR.simple$predictions, ROCR.simple$labels)

gain <- performance(pred, "tpr", "rpp")
plot(gain, main = "Gain Chart")
```

Comment: I get error `could not find function "prediction"`

Answer (score 1):

Even if the question was asked about 5 years ago, I would like to share that I recently have discovered a nice package that helps build GAIN and LIFT charts, and display gain and lift tables: package name is `CustomerScoringMetrics`.

functions: `cumGainsChart()` , `cumGainsChart()`,  `liftChart()`, `liftTable()`, etc.